# Using scipy stats, how can I implement a statistical test in my if else statement?

Tags: python, if-statement, statistics, scipy

How can a statistical test be implemented within an if else statement in python? I'm using scipy stats. A small portion of my code where I want this implemented is:

```
def choose():

        global sample

        if q1.get() == 1 and q2.get() == 1 and q3.get() == 2 and q4.get() == 2 and  q5.get() == 1 and q6.get() == 2 and q7.get() == 2 and q8.get() == 2 and q9.get() == 2 :
            tkMessageBox.showinfo( 'decision', 'You should use the t-test!')
            stats.ttest_1samp()
            #will do t-test here
            print sample
            # now sample list contains the data for doing t-test,
            #you just need to call t-test to get the results and show it on message box
```

Answer (score 0):

Not clear what you are trying to test for. `stats.ttest_1samp()` takes two parameters, one is a sample of observations (in your case `sample`, should be list of float/int values), the other is the population mean. T test test if your sample mean is significantly different from the population mean (that you should also provide).

T test returns 2 values, the first is the so called T score and the second is the probability associated with that t score (with small probability indicating the difference between your `sample` mean and the population mean is highly significant). That part is easy, just fetch the values, convert them to `str` and display them somewhere your want in your message box. Something like:

```
MessageBox.showinfo( 't test', "t-value is %s, p=%s"%stats.ttest_1samp(sample, YOUR_POPULATION_MEAN))
```